# Uploading a file in Web view

Tags: android-webview

I am trying to upload a file inside a web view. I am using angular file upload in the UI.

But after the page load, nothing happens in the webview. The ngf-select dont seems to be responding.

TIA.

Comment: Seems to be this link helps: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/1696

Answer (score 0):

Check if these are added in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```